# Show that the intersection of two measurable sets is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to show that the intersection of two measurable sets is measurable using the following theorem:

If $E\in\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable set, then the following assertion is equivalent to the measurability of $E$:

There is a $G_{\delta}$ set $G$ containing $E$ for which $m^*(G\setminus E)=0$.

And I am not sure where to start. Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Let $E,E'$ be measurable sets. Let $E\subset G$ and $E'\subset G'$ where $G,G'$ are $G_{\delta}$ sets with $m(^*G \setminus E)=0=m^*(G' \setminus E').$ Then $$G\cap G'= D\cup (E\cap E')$$  $$\text { where }\quad  D=A\cup B \cup C$$   $$\text { where }\quad A=G\cap (G' \setminus E'),\;\;  B=G'\cap (G \setminus E),\;\;   C=(G \setminus E)\cap (G' \setminus E').$$ Each of $A,B, C$ is a subset of a  set of outer measure $0$ so each of $A,B,C$ has outer measure $0.$ So $$m^*(D)=m^*(A\cup B\cup C)\leq m^*(A)+m^*(B)+m^*(C)=0.$$ And the intersection of two $G_{\delta}$ sets is a $G_{\delta}$ set so $G\cap G'$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set. And $D=(G\cap G') \setminus (E\cap E').$

Comment: I think I understand this argument. If I am interpreting this correctly, we are using the fact that $D\cup (E\cap E^')$ is measurable to show that $G\cap G^'$ is measurable? I am confused, however, about how you constructed $A$, $B$, and $C$, and also about your last comment, that $D=(G\cap G^')\setminus (E\cap E^')$. I don't see how this helps us.

Comment: (1). The point of the last sentence is just to summarize: We want a $G_{\delta}$ set  $G''$ such that $m^*(G''\setminus (E\cap E'))=0.$  We have $G''=G\cap G'$ and $m^*(G''\setminus (E\cap E'))=m^*(D)=0.$.....(2).  $G\cap G'$ is measurable because it is a $G_{\delta}$ set.

Comment: Let $U=G\setminus E$ and $U'=G'\setminus E'.$ Then $G\cap G'=$ $(E\cup U)\cap (E'\cap U')=$ $(E\cap E')\cup (E\cap U')\cup (E'\cap V)\cup C.$.. I could have called $E\cap U' $  and $ E'\cap U,$ respectively, $A'$ and $B'$.They are $m^*$-$0$ sets, as $A'\subset U'$ and $B'\subset U.$  Then I would not need $A$ and $B$.  That would have been easier to see. But I don't feel like doing a re-write.